# How to detect if there is same word while saving data using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, save, edit

- **scenario**: I have 2 supplies named "chair" and "table"
- **problem**: When I tried to edit the name("table") into "chair", it
  saves... it must go to the else statement...
- **database**: MS Access
- **IDE**: Visual Basic 2012

  ```
  rs.Open("Select * from tblCateringSupplies where CateringSupplyID= '" & Me.SuppID & "' or CateringSupplyName='" & Me.SuppName & "' ", con, 3, 3)           

  If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
      rs.Update()
      rs("CateringSupplyID").Value = Me.SuppID
      rs("CateringSupplyName").Value = Me.SuppName
      rs("Quantity").Value = Me.SuppQuantity
      rs.Update()
      rs.Close()
      con.Close()
  Else
      rs.Close()
      con.Close()

      MsgBox("Supply Already Exist", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error Adding")
  End If
  ```

Comment: I think you need to rephrase this.

Comment: Are you case-sensitive?

Comment: no... btw, that is for edit/save

Comment: try logging the Id of the tblCateringSupplies record you are updating and cross check if it is the one you are anticipating. You might have a problem because CateringSupplyID= '" & Me.SuppID  might be true even if CateringSupplyName does not match.

Answer (score 1):

The line `If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then` checks whether the name or id already exists. At the moment, it only runs the next few lines if the record does exists, if it doesn't it will run the else. It seems like you want it the other way around.

Replace this line with `If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then` and this will go to the else if a record with the same name or id number already exists.

Comment: I already tried that, yes it works.. but it keeps on going to the else statement if I change the name into another...